# How to rewire a LVDS Cable?

Tags: connector, lcd, wiring

I have a samsung LTN154X3-L03 LCD screen from an old laptop. And I was trying to use it as a second display.

I bought the [t.vst59.031 lcd controler board](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/272086508548). The problem is that this board doesn't come with the LVDS cable (or inverter).

Looking at the datasheets I was able to map most of the pins, except two (pins number 6 and 7).

While trying to map the pins from the laptop's LVDS cable (FI-XB30SL-HF10) to the CN12 conector of the LCD t.vst59.031 Controller I came up with this:
[image]

But I'm struggling to map the pin 6 (CLKEDID or DDC Clock) and 7 (DATADID)

With this configuration I was able to see some noise in the screen (very dark since I don't have the inverter set up yet) but it's still not right.
Does anyone know where the CLKEDID and DDC Clock pins should go?

This might also help:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The two pins are for the EDID (display identifier). Your controller may not have connections for it, or they may be on another connector.

If no connections are present, these can be left either floating or connected with a weak pull-up resistor to VEEDID. In this case the driver probably has some built in configuration that allows it to specify to the graphics card what resolution it should be.

Comment: Many thanks Tom. From what you could see in my table (first pic) am I making the correct mappings?

Comment: I also have my doubts about regarding the ground pins. The old LVDS cable that I used has about 5 different ground wires. But looking closely (and measuring with a multimeter) they were all part of one big branch of ground wire at the center of the cable. For that reason I only connected 2 of them to the lcd controller. could this cause an (impedance) issue?

Comment: @Txugo Connections make sense. The multiple grounds are essentially shielding. I'd connect the clock ground to P14, and the three data grounds to P13. The power ground can go to P4/5.